# How to read a time like "10:55" from a text file so that we can do calculation with it in C programming language?

Tags: c, function, file, text, atoi

I am trying to read a time like data (i.e. 10:55) from a text file and assign it in such a way that I can do calculations with it. For instance if I want to covert 10 hrs and 55 minutes from 10:55 into minutes: 
10*60+55=655. But 10:55 contains ':' so I can't directly assign it to an integer. 
So far I was able to solve this problem using atoi(char *ptr)function which coverts the numbers inside a string into integer type data.The code is running just fine but I am not sure how this function works. Because the string "10:55" contains a non numeric value so shouldn't it return junk value immediately when it detects ":".But in my case it returns 10 and then, after I shifted the pointer by 3 places it gives 55.
So it will be really helpful if someone elaborates how this function exactly works.

Finally is there any other way of solving this problem without using atoi() function and only using basic C programming techniques. If yes then please share your code and explanation with me.Thanks a lot for helping. Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int hh,mm;
    char startingtime[6];
    int strtimearr[2];

    FILE *start=fopen("start.txt","w");
    if(start==NULL)
    {
        printf("FILE DOES NOT EXIST");


    }

    printf("START TIME\n");
    printf("->HOUR(hh):");
    scanf("%d",&hh);
    printf("->MINUTE(mm):");
    scanf("%d",&mm);

    fprintf(start,"%d:%d",hh,mm);
    fclose(start);

    start = fopen("start.txt", "r");

    if(start==NULL)
    {
        printf("FILE DOES NOT EXIST");


    }
    fscanf(start, "%s", startingtime);
    fclose(start);

    //puts(startingtime);

    char *s1= startingtime;


    strtimearr[0] = atoi(s1);
    strtimearr[1] = atoi(s1+3);



    printf("Time : %d:%d \nconverted to minute : %d",strtimearr[0],strtimearr[1],(strtimearr[0]*60+strtimearr[1]));


}
```

Comment: The man page for `atoi` states *The function stops reading the input string at the first character that it cannot recognize as part of a number.* That is how it is able to convert `"10:55"` to `10`.

Comment: Part of good reading involves detecting invalid input.  Do you want to limit hours to [0...23] and minutes to [0...59]?  if not what limits?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica . You are right i have noticed that so I fixed it by prompting the user to input the correct value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works but is not robust. If the user gives a number greater than 99 for hour or minute, you will write more than 5 bytes to the file. Then at read time you will read past end of `startingtime` array invoking Undefined Behavious. On the other hand, if hour is less than 10, the minute field will start at position 2 and not 3.

For IO, the rule is *be strict when writing and tolerant when reading*. So I advise you to use a stricter format for writing: `fprintf(start,"%2d:%02d",hh,mm);` or `fprintf(start,"%02d:%02d",hh,mm);` to be consistent for values less than 10.

At read time, you could at least limit size with `fscanf(start, "%5s", startingtime);` and then decode with `sscanf`:

```
int cr = sscanf(startingtime, "%d:%d", strtimearr, strtimearr+1);
```

Or directly decode at read time with `fscanf`:

```
int cr = fscanf(start, "%d:%d", strtimearr, strtimearr+1);
```

and control that `cr` is 2 before printing the result.

Answer (score 2):

> How to read a time like “10:55” from a text file

**You could use [fscanf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf)**,  or combine [fgets](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) (or maybe [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) or even on Linux [readline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readline.3.html) ...) and `sscanf` or [strtol](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtol.htm) **but then don't forget to test its return value** (some `int` for `fscanf` etc...). You might be interested by the `%n` format control string directive to `fscanf` or [sscanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sscanf.3.html) ....

You could, on POSIX or Linux systems, use [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html) facilities. So `#include <time.h>`  then use [strptime(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strptime.3.html) or [getdate(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getdate.3.html).

You could read byte by byte and use [fgetc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc). Check for error conditions (at least `EOF`). Be aware of UTF-8, in 2020 it is almost [everywhere](https://utf8everywhere.org/) ....

### Don't forget to check for [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) errors.

A time like `123:456` in your text file probably don't make sense, and you should check for such input mistakes (and probably give at least the line number where such an input does not make sense).

Read at least about [errno(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) and [perror(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html)

Your program should use `perror` or [strerror(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strerror.3.html) when `fopen` fails. Be also aware that `stdout` is *usually* line buffered (except in command [pipelines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix))). Consider using [fflush](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fflush) and/or [setvbuf](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setvbuf.3.html).

Read of course [*how to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [*what every C programmer should know about undefined behavior*](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html). Consider reading the C11 standard [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) ...

Enable all warnings and debug info when [compiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler). If you use a recent [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler on your C code, compile it [with](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`.

Answer (score 1):

The first part of your question, was already answered as a comment.

Regarding the second question, you could use `fscanf` to read the integer values directly from the file instead of reading a char array and converting it to an int by `atoi`:

```
fscanf(start,"%d:%d", &strtimearr[0], &strtimearr[1]);
```

If `fscanf` is successful, it returns the count of successfully read items, otherwise EOF is returned.